# Help with new arrow notation

Tags: notation, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am working through a description of gradient descent and I'm having trouble finding the definition of a couple notations, an arrow and a single quote, v→v′=v−η∇C. I normally express a derivative with a single quote f'(x) but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

The source of this equation is here http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html, about 3/4 of the way down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be read as $v$ tends to $v'$ (v-prime) which is equal to $v$ minus $\eta$ times $\nabla C$.

v-prime, written as $v'$ in the expression is another variable which has something to do with the perturbation $\Delta_{V}$ defined in the link you gave. $\Delta_{V} = v - v'$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
  v \rightarrow v' = v-\eta \nabla C.
\tag{15}\end{eqnarray}$$

is a function which maps the velocity to the derivative of the velocity:

> This gives us a way of following the gradient to a minimum, even when C is a function of many variables, by repeatedly applying the update rule
>   $$\begin{eqnarray}
>   v \rightarrow v' = v-\eta \nabla C.
> \tag{15}\end{eqnarray}$$
>   You can think of this update rule as defining the gradient descent algorithm. It gives us a way of repeatedly changing the position vv in order to find a minimum of the function C.

Comment: Could I say the right side of the equation is the function that maps v to v prime with → a notion for mapping?